# How can I index a XML file stored in S3 through AWS lambda nodejs function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have XML files stored in an S3 bucket. 
I have set up an ElasticSearch domain and want to index those files in the bucket through AWS lambda.

I probably have to use this dependency.

```
var elasticSearch = require('elasticsearch');
```

I can see the curl command in Amazon [Getting Started Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-gsg-upload-data.html)

```
curl -XPUT elasticsearch_domain_endpoint/movies/_doc/1 -d '{"director": "Burton, Tim", "genre": ["Comedy","Sci-Fi"], "year": 1996, "actor": ["Jack Nicholson","Pierce Brosnan","Sarah Jessica Parker"], "title": "Mars Attacks!"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

How can I do this through nodejs in a lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at [amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples) and [s3_lambda_es.js](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-elasticsearch-lambda-samples/blob/master/src/s3_lambda_es.js)